# ScrollViewer's ScrollToHorizontalOffset not working in Windows 8 app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I have a Windows Store app with a `ScrollViewer` and an `Image` in it. When i double tap on the `ScrollViewer` I want it to zoom the Image to its width. This part is not a problem but I also want the `Image` to be centered after it has beed zoomed in.

I tried calling the `ScrollToHorizontalOffset` method on the `ScrollViewer` but It does not seem to work with any number I give it. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the offset only works for the non-zoomed view where your image fills the ScrollViewer completely and thus can't be scrolled. You could try setting the image dimensions so that it is larger than the ScrollViewer, but set original ZoomFactor, so that it fills the ScrollViewer at first. Then zooming and scrolling might work.

Comment: I already start with a zoom, I zoom the make the Image fit the height and after the tap I want to to firt the height. There is nothing to scrool before the image loads for the first time and sets the zoom of the ScrollViewer

Answer (score 0):

Assign a SizeChangedEvent in the scrollviewer.

```
<ScrollViewer SizeChanged="OnSizeChange"></ScrollViewer>
```

like this. Then it is better to place your image inside a canvas. So your code will be probably like this.

```
<ScrollViewer SizeChanged="OnSizeChange" x:Name="scrl">
   <Canvas RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" x:Name="main">
       <Image source="" Canvas.Top="insert desire double value here", Canvas.Left="Same goes here"/>
   </Canvas>
</ScrollViewer>
```

then in the code behind you can change the height and width of your canvass depending on the scroll viewer

Main.Width = scrl.ViewPortWidth;
   Main.Height = scrl.ViewPortHeight;

You can experiment on the size of the `canvass` while adding a `double tap event` to it. Changing the size of the `canvas` can zoom in or out the `image` because the image is inside the `canvass`

Answer (score 0):

Try with 'ChangeView' instead of 'ZoomToFactor'